# Regex for ASP.NET url rewrite

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting

Sample text =

```
legacycard.ashx?save=false&iNo=3&No=555
```

Sample pattern =

```
^legacycard.ashx(.*)No=(\d+)
```

Want to grab group #2 value of "555" (the value of "No=" in the sample text)

In Expresso, this works, but in ASP.NET UrlRewrite, it is not catching.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably your regexp is ungreedy, and so it catches it matches **No=3** with  **No=(\d+)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something along these lines:

```
^legacycard.ashx\?(?:.+&)*No=(\d+)
```

The `\?` will escape the question mark that normally separates the URL and the parameters, then you make sure that it will capture every parameter key/value pair (anything that ends on `&`) before the parameter you actually care about.  Using `?:` lets you specify that the set of brackets is non capturing (I'm assuming you won't need any of the data, has the potential to slightly speeds up your regex) and leaves you just `555` captured.  The added benefit of this approach is that it'll work regardless of parameter order.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, your regex should match the entire string

> legacycard.ashx?save=false&iNo=3&No=555

not sure why you have groups, but groups should also return

> ?save=false&iNo=3&

and

> 555

For good measure you should know that the . in `legacycard.ashx` is also interpreted by regex and you would normally escape it, in this case it dosen't matter because a single dot matches everything, also a dot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^legacycard.ashx(\?No=|.*?&No=)(\d+)
```

this should work.

Comment: You don't necessarily know if there will be more arguments after or not or that the order of the parameters will always be the same.

Comment: Ok, I thought that it will be always at the end as your regexp did not cover anything behind `No=(\d+)`. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: It's a reasonable assumption, I prefer the point of view that param order is an implementation detail so I try not to rely on it the best I can, but it may not matter in this case.  Also, once you've captured the part that you care about you probably don't need to specify what the rest of the string will look like in the regex.

Comment: You are right, anyway, does adding ampersand before **No** solves your problem?

Comment: Not really my problem =).  It'd address the issue you brought up in the comment (which was an excellent point) but would fail if `No` was the first parameter as the URL would be `something.ashx?No=555&...`.

Comment: Again, it's not an issue, you gave a perfectly good answer, these were just suggestions.

Comment: LOL, sorry @R0MANARMY I must be to tired. I have not noticed that it is not your question. ;)

Comment: Don't worry about it, happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this regex:

```
^legacycard\.ashx\?save=(false|true)&iNo=(?<ino>\d+)&No=(?<no>\d+)
```

Then Regex Replace with

```
${no}
```